# Disable interactions on mat-slider and keeping css styles

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material2

I'm trying to make a readonly mat-slider with a thumb Label always on screen.

I have my mat-slider component

```
<mat-slider
    class="example-margin"
    [disabled]="false"
    [thumbLabel]="true"
    [tickInterval]="tickInterval"
    [(ngModel)]='value'
    >
</mat-slider>
```

To keep Thumb Label always visible I have used these css properties

```
::ng-deep .mat-slider-thumb-label {
  transform: rotate(45deg) !important;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 !important;
}

::ng-deep .mat-slider-thumb {
  transform: scale(0) !important;
}

::ng-deep .mat-slider-thumb-label-text {
  opacity: 1 !important;

}
```

To stop interaction with the `mat-slider` I used `disabled=true` but when I do that the styles disappears and the thumb Label also, then I get an empty space in the bar

[image]

Here what I want but with interactions disabled

[image]

Here a [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b89rlc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fslider-configurable-example.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This you can achieve by disallowing pointer-events on the control. I have modified some CSS and pointer-event also disabled.

CSS

```
::ng-deep .mat-slider-thumb-label {
   transform: rotate(45deg) !important;
   background-color: #ffd740 !important;  <-- make color important so it will not change or disappear in any condition
   border-radius: 50% 50% 0 !important;
}
```

Added inline style

```
style="pointer-events: none;"
```

Stackbliz URL : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fkzv3z

Answer (score 1):

It won't work as expected by disabling it. One solution is to overwrite the disabled class styling, which will be a lot and not the optimum solution.

I would recommend just to disable the pointer-events.

e.g

```
.example-margin {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

This will not allow pointer interactions and your use case is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Sharing a solution that works in Angular 8 without having to use the ::ng-deep (see Note below)

in your mat-slider specify the following

- class:"**cdk-focused**"
- style:"**pointer-events:none**"

Sample HTML code fragement

```
            <mat-slider class="cdk-focused" style="pointer-events:none;" min="0" max="100" thumbLabel="true"
                disabled="false" [value]="item.percent" [displayWith]="formatPercentage">
            </mat-slider>
```

**Note**: [ng-deep is deprecated](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25160)